# Oracle SQL SYSDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LOCAL_TIMESTAMP all returning null

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working on a project that tracks reimbursements, and I'm attempting to store information about when a specific request for a reimbursement is placed in the database. The problem I'm having is that I can't get a timestamp because I'm getting no returns. So far I've tried a couple of things, such as

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual;
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM dual;
```

but they all simply return an empty view, no exceptions thrown. I've tried looking into it but I have been unsuccessful. I'm using Oracle SQL and my database is hosted by AWS. Another odd thing is that all of these initially show up blue like a reserved word in the editor and then quickly turn black like a table name, which makes me wonder if it's just the Oracle SQL developer software acting up, but I tried restarting to no avail so I'm stuck.

Edit: Using JDK 1.8, Oracle SQL Developer version 19.2.1

Comment: What happens in other clients, like SQL\*Pus? What do `select * from dual` or `select date '2020-01-01'` show? If it is only SQL Developer, which version and which JDK version, and are you running as a script or as a statement?

Comment: select date '2020-01-01' says there's a missing "FROM"
select date '2020-01-01' from dual displays date'2020-01-01' as the column name with no data.
I'm running it as a statement, haven't tried other clients because I don't have any other clients

Comment: Maybe there is a table called `dual` with no rows in your schema? What does `select * from dual` show? What does `select * from all_tables where table_name = 'DUAL'` show? If there is such a local table, either insert a row or drop the table. If there is no dual table in your schema, then a DBA may have deleted the row from the system dual table and you must re-insert a row.

Comment: Presumably if the problem is with `dual` then selecting anything from it e.g. `count(*)` will demonstrate the issue, not just the date/time functions.

Comment: You could try doing an ALTER SYSTEM to set FIXED_DATE ( https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams091.htm ). If that works, then the problem is likely the underlying OS not returning a valid clock time to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This is because table with name "dual" has been created in your current schema. You can check the same with `select * from all_tables where table_name = 'DUAL';`

Drop the DUAL table in your schema and then your queries will work.